# How to factorize HTML code without PHP?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been really surprised not finding any question about this:

How can you factorize `HTML5` code without using php, just `HTML5` and `JS`?

I'd like to create a personal project with a `Java`-coded server, then one `HTML`/`JS` client and one `Android` client.

My idea is having a common header for several HTML pages, and I don't want to duplicate code. Naturally, I wanted to make a sort of include, but how?

Maybe should I use a server side page generator, like `Node.js` or something like this. But I'd prefer keeping my project as simple as possible.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "factorize". Do you want to generate HTML on the client's side? If you want to "include" something, then just "download" it with AJAX and append the response text to your `<header>` element.

Comment: You can create all content dynamic like facebook does but it is bad for SEO and your javascript would need some structure.

Comment: ``XML/XSL`` is exactly designed for such things: building a ``xhtml`` upon one or several other ``xhtml``.

Comment: @Xenos Are XHTML and HTML5 compatible?

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk Yes, I'd like to have static HTML pages with JS at client side. How do you implement such a "download"?

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe I think you meant *refactor* PHP-mix-HTML code into plain HTML, via the concept of *separation of concerns*.
There are ways to go about doing it, and on top of my head, I can think of two. 1) Template languages, if you need to pass variables to populate, you need some kind of templating with template processors on server side. 2) via ajax-loaded data, with one of the many javascript templating languages on client side.

Comment: ``XHTML`` is only more respective to ``XML`` than ``HTML5``: all tags must be closed, attributes must not be empty and must be quoted,... [*Differences*](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/differences-html-xhtml/) are syntactic, you'll keep all features of HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, I'd like to have static HTML pages with JS at
>   client side. How do you implement such a "download"?

Well, basically, all you need is to get the page file containing your HTML markup.
The simplest way to do that, is probably by using the [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

**HTML**:

```
<header id="my-header"></header>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(function() {
    $('#my-header').load('url-to-your-html-file'); 
});
```

In `load` method you can also specify:

- parameters to send with your download request, for example if you didn't store your HTML as a file, but were getting it from some kind of web service (written in Java, as you mentioned)
- and a callback (function to execute when download is complete) :)

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/Lvf974pm/

**EDIT**

You could also use other jQuery methods, such as `ajax`, where you can specify that the response data should be cached (your static HTML would be downloaded only once).

Comment: I like your solution. As I am looking for a template javascript framework, do you know if any of AngularJS, RactiveJS or EmberJS (or any other one) can do such a thing instead of JQuery? I am not yet sure whether I'll need JQuery in this project or not.

Comment: I haven't used any of them, but I'm quite certain all of them can do this. It might just be a line or two lines of code more. I once read a little about AngularJS and, if I had to choose instantly, that would probably be my choice.

Answer (score 2):

I actually did this on my current project, to save 8kb of bandwidth for every pageload (and given that it's a game where there are millions of pageloads daily, that adds up REAL fast!)

Basically, take all your unchanging HTML and dump it into a JavaScript file's string. Then you can just have `<div id="header"></div>` in your HTML, and do `document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = "massive string of HTML here";`

This means it's only downloaded once, when the JS file is, and then reused from cache every time after. You can even go more clever by having `data-*` attributes on the `#header` element to define some variable content.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a nice idea! I would prefer having a real separate `HTML`page included, but I'll use your idea if it's not possible!

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea!

Comment: @mplungjan It is. But then again, since when were generic header/footer areas part of the content that you care about with SEO?

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe You could create an HTML file and use AJAX to load it in - this too will allow use of cache to only download that block of HTML once regardless of how many pages are loaded.

Comment: @NietDarkAbsol Have you any technologies to propose?  I have to say I am novice in web development. I'm used to Java backend development.

Answer (score 1):

I would be wary of using Javascript (or any client-side technique) to load in important elements of your webpages. Some users browse the web with Javascript disabled, for security reasons or to improve load time on very slow internet (like people who live away from urban centers and get internet by satellite). If you're using Javascript to load in elements like your navigation menu, these users will not be able to navigate your website at all!

One technique I've been doing on my site is to use HTML pre-processors (such as [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)). It's a bit of a compromise. I write the code in components, but before deploying it to the server, I have to compile the project, which combines all the components into one HTML file per page. I still prefer this to server-side scripting like PHP, because it reduces load time (PHP has to execute each time the page is loaded and adds to the number of HTTP requests, this is just a compile-once technique). It's also a much more flexible factorization technique than loading with Javascript... you can load a "template", but load it with certain variables (such as the page title, or the current page so that your nav menu can be styled appropriately). Another advantage is that Jade is just so much more pleasant to write than HTML.

I do something similar for my CSS using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

If your server is running Java, you could even automate the compile process pretty easily. I automate my compile process by pushing the Jade code to github... I have a [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org) hook that detects changes automatically, compiles them, and pushes the result to my web server via ftp. The process is totally hands-off for me, so as far as I'm concerned, I only ever see my nice pretty factorized Jade code.

Comment: You solution makes sense. But I fear this will be heavy to develop, as it's a little personal project on which I am alone.

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe I was dubious at first too. If you're familiar with node.js (you mentioned it in your post), it's easy. Jade and Sass are both node modules, so installing them and using them won't require extra knowledge. Just specify a source and destination folder, it will find and compile each file for you, maintaining folder structure. Getting fancy with Gruntfiles, automatic continuous integration, etc. is totally unnecessary. The "compiling" takes a miniscule fraction of a second per page.

Comment: I'm not familiar with NodeJS, I just know this exists and I have read one tutorial. That said, I think I'll try to implement a POC to see which solution among all those that have been submitted fits the best to my needs. All of them look promising. Thanks for you proposition.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another potential solution. As I widh to use a JS framework at client side, I think I could use the templates provided by, for example, RactiveJS, EmberJS, AngularJS or whatever.

Those frameworks propose to define HTML templates that can be nested one in another. I have to go further, but this looks promising.